# looking for numbers in a character array

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that reads lines from a file
I need to print out the numbers, the lines read are stored in a character array:

```
char line[255];
//code to read line from file here
for (c=0;c<256;c++)
{
  if (line[c]<58 && line[c]>47)
    printf("the character is: %c\n",line[c]);
}
```

the configuration file has the following lines:

```
buttons 3
```

the result I'd like to get is `the character is 3`, instead I get `3,9,4,4`

Hope I've provided sufficient information.
thanks

Comment: And your problem is... ?

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is actually giving the output you say, since it outputs `newline` and not `,` (if it outputs anything).

Comment: yes, I meant >47   and <58   thanks for that

Comment: Please don't just tinker with the code in response to comments. We won't know what is real and what is mistyped. Post your effective code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Downvoted.

Comment: It was a typo, what I have there now is the real code I'm using

Comment: What about inputs like `button 23`? Are you supposed to read the number `23` or two separate digits `2` and `3`?

Comment: that should be no big deal, I'm modifying the code to multiply the integer byu 10 and adding the number to it
so 0*10+2, then 2*10+3

Comment: Tiny fix: `c<255` (0..254) is 255 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement is wrong.

You can express it much clearer, and more correctly as:

```
if ('0' <= line[c] && line[c] <= '9')
{
    printf("the character is: %c\n",line[c]);
}
```

---

Your loop runs for 256 characters, even though the input of `"buttons"` only has 7 characters.  You're running off into memory that is not yours, and likely finding 9, 4, 4, there by random chance.

You want:

```
for (int c=0; c < 256; ++c)
{
    if (line[c] == '\0')    // If the end of the input is found, stop the loop.
    {
        break;
    }
    if ('0' <= line[c] && line[c] <= '9')
    {
        printf("the character is: %c\n",line[c]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the string terminator :):) didn't think of that
you're answer is perfect, thank you very much, problem solved :D

Answer (score 1):

An extension of abelenky's post:

abelenky presents 2 (out of many) solutions to the problem. An important aspect of writing code is readability. abelenky's first solution maximizes readability.

```
if (line[c] >= '0' && line[c] <= '9')
{
    printf("the character is: %c\n",line[c]);
}
```

Everyone is aware that ASCII characters are mapped to integer values, but not everyone can readily recall the range of values associated with each types of character (numbers, letters, capital letters, etc.).

This is why C supports the single quotes: ' '

It is reasonable to assume that ASCII values for integers increment as do integers from 0-9, thus using '0' and '9' in your conditional statement improves readability. Adopting a more legible style of code **will** improve your and the life of anyone who views your code.

Happy coding!

Comment: A very good tip, I'm trying to improve my code's readability and this should definitely help
thank you both

Comment: No problem! In the scope of readability, my comment regarding ASCII characters is very minimal. You only learn more advantageous techniques with practice!

Comment: Unfortunately, I never see these kinds of problems on my own, I always need someone to look at my code to point out readability problems